# phpMailer causa erro syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION quando hospedado

Tags: phpmailer

Bom estou com um problema no phpMailer estou usando um servidor XAMPP para poder mexer com ele fiz um formulário porem ele esta enviando normalmente para meu email que no caso seria GMAIL no entanto possuo uma hospedagem na localweb e quando coloco meu site no ar e preencho meu formulário ele da o seguinte erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/storage/1/8e/5d/tecmovgruas2/public_html/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 3040
```

trecho do código da linha 3040 que aparece no erro:

```
 protected function clearQueuedAddresses($kind)
    {
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
            $RecipientsQueue = $this->RecipientsQueue;
            foreach ($RecipientsQueue as $address => $params) {
                if ($params[0] == $kind) {
                    unset($this->RecipientsQueue[$address]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->RecipientsQueue = array_filter(
                $this->RecipientsQueue,
                function ($params) use ($kind) {
                    return $params[0] != $kind;
                });
        }
    }
```

vale lembrar que não estou usando esse arquivo segue meu código PHP  e um trecho do formulário do meu site:

O HTML:

```
<form id="main-contact-form1" name="contact-form" action="envio.php" method="post">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Escreva sua Mensagem" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

O PHP:

```
     <?php
$Nome       = $_POST["name"];   // Pega o valor do campo Nome
$Email       = $_POST["email"];   // Pega o valor do campo Telefone
$Assunto      = $_POST["subject"];  // Pega o valor do campo Email
$Mensagem   = $_POST["message"];   // Pega os valores do campo Mensagem

// Variável que junta os valores acima e monta o corpo do email

$Vai        = "Nome: $Nome\n\nE-mail: $Email\n\nAssunto: $Assunto\n\nMensagem: $Mensagem\n";
/*date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
*/
require("phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
require("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

define('GUSER', 'contato@tecmovgruas.com');   // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
define('GPWD', 'lalala');        // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setLanguage('pt');
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.tecmovgruas.com'; // SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 587;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}

// Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER), 

 if (smtpmailer('tecmovlocacao@gmail.com', 'tecmovlocacao@gmail.com', 'renata', 'Assunto do Email', $Vai)) {

    Header("location:obrigado.html"); // Redireciona para uma página de obrigado.

}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
?>
```

OBS: Vale Lembrar que isso esta funcionando perfeitamente local com o xampp somente quando subo o projeto para a web ele para de funcionar.E também criei um domínio de email próprio pela localweb onde meus email vão para la e e redirecionado para minha conta gmail

Comment: O php do seu xampp local pode ser diferente do php do servidor hospedado. outra algumas coisas da hospedagem pode estar desabilitada smtp,email porta 587 diversas outros problemas.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada aqui

Comment: Não acho que seja um problema de PORTA... O mais estranho é que isso deveria corrigir o problema: `if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {`, realmente não sei porque esta ocorrendo isto, qual a versão do teu servidor?

Comment: o serividor xampp voce diz ? se for e a versao 3.2.2

Comment: Não o Xampp é um pacote de programas e não é oficial do PHP, é só um facilitador, ele pode ter mais de uma versão do php, o que eu quero saber é a versão do php instalado na hospedagem @Kirito - Cria um script chamado info.php e coloca esse conteudo `<?php echo phpinfo();` e depois execute e procura aonde fala a versão e me informa.

Comment: assim man e essa a versao PHP Version 5.6.15

Comment: Parece não ter problemas no que apresentou. Lembre-se que o compilador do PHP pode apontar o erro numa linha "errada" quando há erros de `if () else`. Normalmente quando há um `{` ou `( `aberto. Também pode ser a falta do delimitador de linha `;` em algum ponto nos scripts antes da linha apontada pelo erro. O erro pode nem mesmo estar nos códigos do PHPMailier. Você deve criar breakpoints buscando pontos lógicos para eliminar possibilidades de erros até encontrar o local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entre no arquivo class.phpmailer.php e vá até a linha 3040 e substitui o código por esse.

```
protected function clearQueuedAddresses($kind)
{
    //if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
        $RecipientsQueue = $this->RecipientsQueue;
        foreach ($RecipientsQueue as $address => $params) {
            if ($params[0] == $kind) {
                unset($this->RecipientsQueue[$address]);
            }
        }
    //} else {
    //    $this->RecipientsQueue = array_filter(
    //        $this->RecipientsQueue,
    //        function ($params) use ($kind) {
    //            return $params[0] != $kind;
    //        });
    //}
}
```

Meu código de configuração que eu uso no meu servidor e funciona certinho.

```
    $this->mail->isSMTP();
        $this->mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $this->mail->SMTPDebug = false;
        $this->mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $this->mail->Port = 587;
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
```

Comment: apareceu o seguinte erro : Mail error: SMTP Connect() falhou. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: dentro de instantes estou colocando novamente o site no ar se quiser pode ate fazer um teste nele para voce dar uma olhada no erro que da

Comment: @Kirito agora este problema tem algo relacionado com smtp. qual smtp vai usar?

Comment: e assim estou usando um dominio propio que serio o contato@tecmovgruas.com acesso ele via webmail porem de la ele redireciona automaticamente para minha conta gmail porque minha cliente quer receber via gmail

Comment: logo meu smtp nao pode ser gmail e sem tecmovgruas talvez seja esse o erro vou verificar aqui e te aviso ja

Comment: amigo testei com esse smtp:   smpt.tecmovgruas.com e deu esse erro              Mail error: Erro do SMTP: O endereÃ§o do seguinte destinatÃ¡rio falhou: tecmovlocacao@gmail.com: : Recipient address rejected: Access Denied

Comment: @kirito Você tem que usar smtp.gmail você usa aquele serviço do google que você cria dominio personalizado mais usa caixa de entrada do gmail ? isso é só uma mascara mais o dominio aponto como smtp do gmail. então é importante usar o smtp do gmail

Comment: entao pois assim pelo que vi funcionou mais o gmail bloqueou algo assim pois o email vai para o webmail no caso o contato@tecmovgruas e dentro do meu web mail tem um filtro qeu criei que pega esse email que foi para la e encaminha para meu gmail eu fiz assim pois e muito melhor que entrar no webmail e minha cliente prefere assim entao logo se o email vai para o webmail o vorreto nao seria usar o smtp do web mail ?

Comment: atualizei meu post no php para voce poder ver as ediçoes que redultaram nesse novo erro

Comment: Até que pode resolver, mas isto é mais uma gambiarra, o proprio `if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {` deveria resolver o problema. Se o erro esta ocorrendo com a `if` lá é porque tem algo mais errado, temos que procurar a origem do problema. Deve ser outra coisa.

Comment: @Kirito tenta usar porta 465

Comment: TSL mesmo ou mudo para SSL

Comment: @Kirito tenta os 2

Comment: com ssl da o mesmo erro que mensionei por ultimo e com tsl fica carregando infinitamente a pagina ate expirar

Comment: Eu acho que achei problema... o smtp da locaweb para enviar email com ela.. você não pode alterar o (from) de ... o from tem que ser o mesmo usuario de login do smtp.

Comment: O from tem que ser vindo do mesmo dominio que é este contato@tecmovgruas.com

Comment: http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Email_Locaweb_-_Envio_Autenticado

Comment: funcionouuuuuuuuuu amigo muito obrigado pela sua ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Para *Locaweb*, costumo utilizar esse código e funciona bem, caso queira experimentar segue:

```
<?php

if(@$_POST['acao'] == 'envia'){
    $empresa = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['empresa']);
    $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['nome']);


    require_once('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');


    $mail = new PHPMailer();



    $caixaPostalServidorEmail='web@email.com.br';
    $caixaPostalServidorSenha='suasenhadoemail'; // SE USAR $mail->SMTPAuth  = true; 
    // $caixaPostalServidorSenha='suasenhadoemail'; // Comente para não autenticar $mail->SMTPAuth  = false; 

    $caixaPostalServidorNome='contato@email.com.br';

    $enviaFormularioParaEmail='destinatario@email.com.br';
    $enviaFormularioParaNome='Cliente';

    $assunto = "Novo Email";
    $assunto = "$assunto";


    $mensagemConcatenada ="<h2 style='font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif'>Contato do site</h2>
    <hr>
    <strong>Empresa:</strong> $empresa<br />
    <strong>Nome:</strong> $nome<br /> ";

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth  = true; //false para não autenticar
    $mail->Charset   = 'utf8_decode()';
    $mail->Host  = 'smtp.'.substr(strstr($caixaPostalServidorEmail, '@'), 1);
    $mail->Port  = '587';
    $mail->Username  = $caixaPostalServidorEmail;
    $mail->Password  = $caixaPostalServidorSenha;
    $mail->From  = $caixaPostalServidorEmail;
    $mail->FromName  = utf8_decode($caixaPostalServidorNome);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject  = utf8_decode($assunto);
    $mail->Body  = utf8_decode($mensagemConcatenada);


    $mail->AddAddress($enviaFormularioParaEmail,utf8_decode($enviaFormularioParaNome));

    if(!$mail->Send()){
    $mensagemRetorno = 'Erro ao enviar formulário: '. print($mail->ErrorInfo);
    }else{  


    echo"Mensagem enviada";


    } 

}
?>
```